# 2007 Escalade - grease on front axle

Tags: axle, awd, grease, wheel-bearing

07 Escalade 6.2L AWD

I had the front RH wheel off and saw this:

[image: messy]

Is the grease from the wheel bearing, or the axle? Can this sort of thing be repacked, or should I replace the axle (and/or bearing)? I have zero experience with front-wheel or all-wheel drive vehicles, and don't want to unnecessarily replace parts that are just dirty, not broken.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It looks as though the boot has split and is spewing grease all over the place. If there isn't a lot of dirt let into the boot, you should be able to just replace the boot (yes, this is a chore, but a heck of a lot cheaper than replacing the half-shaft). When you replace the boot, you'll want to put some grease back into it to supplement what was lost. If you aren't hearing any noises out of the CVJ when it's turned, you really shouldn't have an issue just replacing the boot.

Oh, and clean that mess up :o)

Comment: Thanks, Paul. (I swear I'm not doing intentionally breaking things.)